# How do I include the .NET Compact Framework as part of a Smart Device CAB Project?

Tags: .net, deployment, compact-framework

I'm working on a VS2008 Smart Device app that includes a Smart Device CAB Project for deployment.  I was surprised to find out that this installer project doesn't install the .NET Compact Framework if necessary.  Can it be made to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a CAB Project to install and run another CAB file - it's a limitation of the CAB installer system (wceload to be exact).  One way to achieve it is to include the CF CAB and then create a [custom setup DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924308.aspx) that expands it after the internal CAB is unpacked.  Of course the CAB project has no provision for correctly updating the INF file to run the custom setup DLL, so you have to manually build the CAB using [CABWIZ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448616.aspx).

Needless to say, the entire CAB installer architecture leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with some work.  See [Automatically Install Multiple CAB Files to a Windows Mobile/Pocket PC Device](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65319/Automatically-Install-Multiple-CAB-Files-to-a-Wind) from codeproject.com